# Difference between the classes System.StringComparer and System.StringComparison?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between these two classes ?

I have used `System.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase()` and `System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase()` and both yield the same results. Do they have any difference or they both same ?

Comment: could you post your case and it's expected results for each. I wonder if you are comparing == vs Equals in terms of references vs values

Comment: `System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is an enum value, not a method. So `System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase()` wouldn't compile. Not sure what you actually meant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`StringComparer` is a `Class` which implements comparison interfaces like `IComparer`, `IEqualityComparer`, `IComparer<String>`, so that it can be used to compare two strings.

`StringComparison` is simply an `Enum` that you can pass in to certain methods to indicate which kind of comparison you want. In that case I suspect the underlying method would use a `StringComparer` to do the actual comparison.

**When to use each**

String specific methods like [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) only accepts a `StringComparison` value, so that's what you would use in this case.

You would use a `StringComparer` for methods which take a comparer as a parameter, and are called in a context where strings will be compared. For example, if you had a `List<String>`, and wanted to [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/234b841s.aspx) that list in a case-insensitive way, you could do:

```
myList.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 8):

The question is: **why to have in a framework both of them ?**

The explanation is this one:

- StringComparison is:

> Specifies the culture, case, and sort rules to be used by certain
>   overloads of the String.Compare and String.Equals methods

- StringComparer is:

> Represents a string comparison operation that uses specific case and
>   culture-based or ordinal comparison rules

Noticed a difference ?

In second case, so in case of `StringComparer` there is a notion of `string comparison operation`, but not `string` type.

In fact, if you look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd465121.aspx#common_string_comparison_methods_in_the_net_framework) you will read simply:

> Some non-string methods that have string comparison as a central
>   operation use the StringComparer type.

An example, from the same link:

```
Array.BinarySearch(this.storedNames, name, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

I use `StringComparer` like a comparison "base" among content of the `array` reference type.

Comment: Excellent answer. To make it even more clear: You should probably never design a method or class where you take a StringComparison as input - you should take as StringComparer instead, as this would allow clients of your code to pass in their own custom comparer if needed. The comparer is extensible, while comparison is not.