# Can't we use StringComparison in HashSet?

Tags: c#

C# 3.5: I can't get this code to compile:

```
HashSet<string> classDeclarations = new HashSet<string>(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

I get this error:

> *Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.StringComparison' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'*

So I can't pass a comparison?

Answer (score 8):

`StringComparison` is an enum used by many string-related functions.
Since `HashSet<T>` has nothing to do with strings, it wouldn't make sense for it to take a `StringComparison`.

You need to use the static properties of the `StringComparer` class, which implement `IEqualityComparer<String>`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it as

```
HashSet<string> myHashSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Having the two seemingly identical functionality sets for these has been an annoyance. Does anyone know if there is a reason for this?

Comment: It appears my question has been asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8918032/16391), but it still feels like a code smell.